# M2 - How to get store information in knockout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, custom-shipping-method, knockout

How can I get store information in KnockOut?

For example: When a customer selects "Pickup @ Store" as shipping method, I need to update the shipping address to the address of the store.

The customer has the option to not ship to his home address but pick the package up up at a physical shop location. In that case the shipping information should show the shop location address and not the customer address. So i need the shop location address configured in the backend of Magento. How can i pass that information (configuration settings) to Knockout?

Comment: What is the `Pickup @ Store" as shipping method`? Can you explain more details?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh: i added some extra information, "Pickup @ Store" is to not ship the package but get it at a physical store

Comment: You can store the shop shipping details in window.checkoutData element, and you can use it from knockout js

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is in the comments above

> You can store the shop shipping details in window.checkoutData
>   element, and you can use it from knockout js – seeni

Useful link to add variable to window.checkoutConfig: http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-more-variable-to-window-checkoutconfig/